# pyspark XML read producing empty dataframe

Tags: xml, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm trying to read XML file with pySpark. The problem is, it produces empty dataframe. I was able to read different files without any issues.

Here is the XML structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<TAG1>
  <TAG2 id="ID1"> 
      <field1>some value</field1>
      <field2>some value</field2>
      <field3></field3>
  </TAG2>
  <TAG2 id="ID2"> 
      <field1>some value</field1>
      <field2></field2>
      <field3></field3>
  </TAG2>
  <TAG2 id="ID3"> 
      <field1>some value</field1>
      <field2>some value</field2>
      <field3>some value</field3>
  </TAG2>
</TAG1>
```

I tried different options when reading the file but none of them works.

```
df = spark.read \
    .format('com.databricks.spark.xml') \
    .options(rowTag='TAG2') \
    .options(nullValue='') \
    .options(emptyValue='') \
    .load(xmlFile)
```

**UPDATE:**

I copied the file contents to a new file, saved it and it loaded without any problems.
It seems like the original file is causing problems. I tried to put various encodings in read options but still was not able to load the original file.

Comment: xmlPath = "dbfs:/FileStore/tables/smplxml.xml"
df = spark.read \
    .format('com.databricks.spark.xml') \
    .options(rowTag='TAG2') \
    .options(nullValue='') \
    .options(emptyValue='') \
    .load(xmlPath)
df.display()

try this

Comment: @DileeprajnarayanThumula This is the same code I used and it's not working

Comment: %scala
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
    import com.databricks.spark.xml._
    
    val df = spark.read
      .option("rowTag", "TAG2")
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .xml(xmlPath)
    
    df.printSchema()
    df.show(truncate=false)

Comment: Can you please try this

Comment: @DileeprajnarayanThumula I noticed that everything works fine when I copied file contents to a new file. Seems like a problem with file itself, not an xml structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File happened to be encoded in UTF-16, but setting this encoding didn't solve the issue. I managed to load the file only after passing another parameter - **charset**.

```
df = spark.read \
    .format('com.databricks.spark.xml') \
    .options(rowTag='TAG2') \
    .options(nullValue='') \
    .options(encoding='UTF-16LE') \
    .options(charset='UTF-16') \
    .load(xmlFile)
```